# Remote IP Address

Tags: html, perl, web, ip, interchange

I want to get the remote IP of the machine accessing my website.
I am using Interchange Server IC. IC perl code in embedded into HTML.

In perl i could find out this solution :

```
use CGI; <!-- load the cgi module-->
print "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n";
my $q = new CGI; <!--create a CGI object-->
print $q->remote_host(); <!-- print the user ip address-->

use $ENV{REMOTE_HOST} 
use $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR}
```

but syntax of IC is different and am new to it.
Pls help.

Thanks
Rachel

Comment: What is this IC you speak of? (Link please) Having a hard time figuring it out using google. More relevant: What protocol or API does it use to communicate between itself and the perl process if it's not CGI?

Comment: http://www.icdevgroup.org/interchange-doc-5.2.0/icfull.pdf

Comment: I am talking about this IC http://www.icdevgroup.org/i/dev

Comment: Thanks @ikegami for the reply.pls tell me how to get IP

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558973/disable-command-button-in-ic-interchange this is another query asked by me.plz ckh if this can help for this IP question

Comment: What's wrong with `my $ip = $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR};`

Comment: my $ip = $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR}; printed as it is but no value

Comment: how to print this $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR}; value on my html page

Comment: @wk.thanks but its not showing IP on the page

Comment: Maybe you should ask on IC IRC channel, most prompt way for urgent need

Comment: Thanks @wk can you paste the link of IC IRC channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [file](http://git.icdevgroup.org/?p=interchange.git;f=lib/Vend/Payment/SagePay.pm;hb=HEAD;a=blob) linked from the documentation use the CGI module and fetches the remote address using CGI's `remote_addr` function, so I presume that information is available to you.

Doing a reverse DNS lookup of the remote address can be expensive to do, so web servers don't always do this by default. `remote_host` would return nothing on those systems.