# Disable Command Button in IC (Interchange)

Tags: html, perl, button, interchange

I want to disable my command button when the no of hits reach 100 ,retrieving no of hits from mysql using IC.

I am doing something like this but its not working.

```
my $cc= [sql-param hits];
[if $cc>= 100 ]
<input type="Submit" name="cv" value="Vote" disabled="true"><br /><br />
[/if]
```

Thanks
Isha

Comment: HTML works fine, please check if your if block is working or not!

Comment: Yes HTML works fine but I don know what is wrong with block written in IC.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to stick with ITL, if you can.  You shouldn't need Perl code for this.

I haven't messed with IC in a while, but something similar to this (within the `[query]` tag, of course) might work...

```
[if-sql-param hits >= 100]
 <input type="submit" name="cv" value="Vote" disabled="disabled"><br><br>
[/if-sql-param]
```

I'm not seeing the point of outputting either a disabled button or nothing, though.  You might just want to output the "disabled" attribute if the condition's true.

```
<input type="submit" name="cv" value="Vote" 
 [if-sql-param hits >= 100] disabled="disabled"[/if-sql-param]>
<br>
<br>
```